# Keep Element In Middle Of Excess Space With CSS calc() Function

Tags: html, css, width, css-calc

I have a `<main>` HTML element that takes up 80% of the `<body>` element on a page and it has a max-width value of `max-width: 1220px`.

Outside of this `<main>` element I have a small SVG arrow - is it possible with the CSS `calc()` function to have this so it is always in the middle of the area outside the main element on the left hand side?

If I didn't have a max-width property I could just do `left: 10%` but this only works up until the `main` element hits it max-width.

The full code is below and I've managed to get it so it aligns with the left hand side of the main element, but I can't get it so it is halfway across the white space on the left hand side. I'm thinking it may not be possible in CSS.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/bGEJjwX

**Note 1:** When viewing the snippet below you'll need to view it full-page because of the max-width value.

**Note 2:** What I am trying to do is illustrated in the below image.

[image]

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 6rem 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 1220px;
}

.down-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  bottom: 25vh;

  /* THIS IS THE BIT I NEED HELP WITH */
  left: calc((100% - 1220px) / 2);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="row"></div>
</main>
<svg class="down-arrow" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 410.95 355.89">
  <polygon fill="#000" points="205.47 354.89 410.08 0.5 0.87 0.5 205.47 354.89" /></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the arrow is absolutely positioned, it makes it a lot more complicated to position it relative to the main element. Instead, you can achieve the same effect (if i'm understand what you're looking for correctly!) using a wrapping container and Flexbox (or default CSS to vertically and horizontally center the child elements, I just prefer flex).

What I did was wrap the main element and the arrow in a div, labeled with a class of container. This way, we can position the main and svg relative to each other while still maintaining the flow of the application.

Display flex automatically aligns child elements in a row, which puts the svg and main elements next to each other. Adding align-items and justify-content center ensures that everything remains vertically and horizontally centered. I removed the margin: 0 auto; from main and the absolute positioning from the svg since it's no longer necessary.

Pen with changes, or see below: https://codepen.io/xenvi/pen/OJMGweV

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
  
 .container {
   display: flex;
 }

main {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 6rem 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 1220px;
}

.down-arrow {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  bottom: 25vh;
}

.arrow-container, .end-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow-container">
    <svg class="down-arrow" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 410.95 355.89">
    <polygon fill="#000" points="205.47 354.89 410.08 0.5 0.87 0.5 205.47 354.89" /></svg>  
  </div>
  <main>
    <div class="row"></div>
  </main>
  <div class="end-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Xenvi - that isn't what I'm trying to do. I've edited the question and attached an image which hopefully makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Hi, my apologies! I see what you mean now. I updated my pen here: https://codepen.io/xenvi/pen/OJMGweV. One method (shown in pen) which bounces off of my idea with using flexbox is to add a spacing container after the main container. This makes the row even with the arrow container and spacing container taking the same space (10% min, increases evenly when main has max-width) and main being 80%. Flex-grow makes the arrow and spacing container always fill up the remaining space evenly

Comment: Thanks @xenvi. The Codepen example worked, but this answer still contained the old code so I've just copied it over to save you having to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `left: calc((100% - 1220px)/4);`. From `100%` we remove the width to get the white space. Then we divide by `2` to get only the left part and we divide again by `2` to get half of it.

You can also use `min()` to make it working for small screen too:

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 6rem 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 1220px;
}

.down-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  top: 25vh;
  left: calc((100% - min(1220px,80%))/4);
  transform:translate(-50%); /* don't forget this to get a perfect centring */
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="row"></div>
</main>
<svg class="down-arrow" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 410.95 355.89">
  <polygon fill="#000" points="205.47 354.89 410.08 0.5 0.87 0.5 205.47 354.89" /></svg>
```